# IMage slider using carousal js file

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create image slide using carousal.js as it is here:

[Carousal slider](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

But I dont understand which css files does it use? I included bootstrap.css but it does not contains the required class.

Including bootstrap.js and carousal.js files are enough for this slider?

Comment: If you look in the bootstrap.min.css at the example page you will find all carousel classes starting at line 4554.

Comment: Could it be that you allways produce the same typo in the word carousel? I mean, you got it 4 times wrong in your question:-)

Comment: @mainguy: ok carousel class is there but `class="carousel slide` where `slide` class is not there in bootstrap.css file